# Python bitwise logic to operate LEDs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bit-manipulation

So i'm currently playing with my Raspberry Pi and 7 segment(actually 8 because there is dot) display and i need help. I know how to operate it using single LEDs(so for example i know which LEDs i need to light up to create "1" so i can basically operate it) but there was code in manual that's using some bitwise logic which is far beyond my understanding.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

pins = [11,12,13,15,16,18,22,7]
dats = [0x3f,0x06,0x5b,0x4f,0x66,0x6d,0x7d,0x07,0x7f,0x6f,0x77,0x7c,0x39,0x5e,0x79,0x71,0x80]

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    for pin in pins:
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)   # Set pin mode as output
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

def writeOneByte(val):
    GPIO.output(11, val & (0x01 << 0))  
    GPIO.output(12, val & (0x01 << 1))  
    GPIO.output(13, val & (0x01 << 2))  
    GPIO.output(15, val & (0x01 << 3))  
    GPIO.output(16, val & (0x01 << 4))  
    GPIO.output(18, val & (0x01 << 5))  
    GPIO.output(22, val & (0x01 << 6))  
    GPIO.output(7,  val & (0x01 << 7)) 

def loop():
    while True:
        for dat in dats:
            writeOneByte(dat)
            time.sleep(0.5)

def destroy():
    for pin in pins:
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()             # Release resource

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the child program destroy() will be executed.
        destroy()
```

The code above cycles through 0-9 and A-F and then dot.

Every help/explanation/advice is welcome.

EDIT: I GET IT NOW. Just turned on my brain. CLOSED.

Comment: I posted an answer anyway, just in case somebody stumbles upon this page from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SETUP

I'm going to refer to this image I found on a [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/EngineeringStudents/comments/3pl9jv/designed_my_first_pcb_hope_i_made_you_all_proud/):

[image: seven segment truth table]

So the pins correspond to the segments as follows:

**A**:    11
**B**:    12
**C**:    13
**D**:    15
**E**:    16
**F**:    18
**G**:    22

---

Now let's see what happens when we call `writeOneByte` with the first value in the list named `dats`, i.e **0x3f**.

The first line in the function is

```
GPIO.output(11, val & (0x01 << 0))
```

`val` holds the value **0x3f** which is what was passed into the function. This value is equivalent to **0b00111111** in binary. Looking again at the diagram, we see that the letters **A**-**G** actually correspond to each bit, from the least significant (right most bit) to the second most significant bit. The most significant bit is reserved for the dot.

---

### BITWISE OPERATIONS

The `<<` is the left-shift operator. The code `0x01 << 0` means shift the number **0x01** *zero* bits to the left. Therefore, the operation leaves the number unchanged, and the result is still **0x01**, which is equivalent to **0b00000001**.

Next up is `&`, the bitwise `AND` operator. This performs a logical `AND` operation on a bit-by-bit basis. It's easy to see in an example:

```
0b00111111
0b00000001
----------
0b00000001
```

Essentially what we are doing is checking the first (least significant) bit of the number in `val` and checking to see whether the corresponding pin should have a `HIGH` or a `LOW` output. In this case, the value of the first bit is 1. After the `AND` operation, the value passed to `GPIO.output` for pin 11 (which corresponds to segment **A**), is **0b00000001**. This outputs a `HIGH` value, because anything that is not all zeroes translates into a boolean true.

The process is repeated on the remaining lines of code:

```
GPIO.output(12, val & (0x01 << 1))
```

This time **0b00000001** is shifted 1 bit to the left, yielding **0b00000010**. We perform the bitwise `AND` again:

```
0b00111111
0b00000010
----------
0b00000010
```

which is also a `HIGH` output for pin 12, and thus segment B is on.

In fact, the only time we get a `LOW` is with pin 7, in the last line:

```
GPIO.output(7,  val & (0x01 << 7))

0b00111111
0b01000000
----------
0b00000000
```

As you can see in the diagram, the bits that drive the pins take on the appropriate values to yield the number `0` in the given display arrangement.